# Lists sorting in Python (transpose)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sorting, transpose

I have arbitrary lists, for instance here are three lists:

```
a = [1,1,1,1]
b = [2,2,2,2]
c = [3,3,3,3]
```

And I want transpose them together in order to get the output like this:

```
f_out = [1,2,3]
g_out = [1,2,3]
...
n_out = [1,2,3]
```

As, you can see, I just converted "columns" to "rows".

The issue is a solution has to be independent of the lists length.

For example:

```
a = [1,1]
b = [2]
c = [3,3,3]
# output
f_out = [1,2,3]
g_out = [1,3]
n_out = [3]
```

Comment: You might want to look into `itertools.zip_longest` -- That's _almost_ what you want, you'd just have to filter out the extra padding.

Comment: @mgilson Thank you! I think it can help me :)

Comment: For anyone else just staring at this question and wondering what the relationship between the input and output is, it's treating it almost like a transpose matrix. IOW, `f`, `g`, and `h` result from lining `a`, `b`, and `c` up horizontally and reading top to bottom.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> a = [1,1]
>>> b = [2]
>>> c = [3,3,3]
>>> f,g,h=[[e for e in li if e is not None] for li in zip_longest(a,b,c)]
>>> f
[1, 2, 3]
>>> g
[1, 3]
>>> h
[3]
```

If `None` is a potential valid value in the lists, use a sentinel [object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object) instead of the default `None`:

```
>>> b = [None]
>>> sentinel = object()
>>> [[e for e in li if e is not sentinel] for li in zip_longest(a,b,c, fillvalue=sentinel)]
[[1, None, 3], [1, 3], [3]]
```

Comment: It is zip_longest for python3

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Good catch -- fixed